# "bending" lines to a predetermined shape

Tags: qgis, symbology, linestring

I have a dataset with AIS-transponder information.

---

A AIS-transponder is a digital system onboard a ship that sends/receives information to/from the vessels within range of the VHF transceiver in a SOTDMA defined interval.

---

The set has linestrings, every line is the track of one journey of one ship. The line starts at the point of entry and ends when the vessel changes his status to "moored" (or the otherway around)
The vertices of the line are the points where the vessels transmitted. 
This presents me with a problem, as seen in the following shot:[image: AIS data in yellow/blue]

The tranmission interval depends on the type of ship and speed (and a few other parameters). In a lot of cases this means that in area's with sharp turns the line between two vertices is displayed over land.

In the screenshot above i have displayed a red-dotted-line.
Is there a way to force the line between the vertices to stay within the red-dotted-line?

The data is stored in a geopackage with one layer per year, starting from 2009.I use QGIS 3.6.

Comment: There might be a way with the `Snap geometries to layer` tool. You'd need to create a standard route for each channel, select the lines that cross land, and snap them to the nearest channel route.